# Convert triple-nested list to dataframe (list has multiple data-types: string, int, float)

Tags: python, dataframe, list, jupyter-notebook

Consider this python code snippet:

```
triple_nested_list = [[[1, 2, '3', 4.0], [5, 6, '7', 8.0]]]
column_names = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']
```

I am trying to convert this triple-nested list to dataframe which includes a string, an int, and a float value.

While doing so, I am getting error as:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Possible solutions i tried
#1

```
df = pd.DataFrame(triple_nested_list[0], columns=column_names)
```

#2

```
flat_list = [inner for outer in triple_nested_list for inner in outer]
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list, columns=column_names)
```

I am expecting the triple-nested list converted to a DataFrame

Comment: Hi Atharv, what version of Pandas are you using? The exact code you provided works on my end.